# OpenXml Word ,, Set RTL text along with font size

Tags: openxml

i am trying to set a font size and right to left attrib to a word table cell text
but it always take one of them , whenever i set them both it only takes the RTL attrib
here is my code

```
Paragraph p = cell.Elements<Paragraph>().First();
        if (p == null || p.Elements<Run>() == null || p.Elements<Run>().ToArray().Length < 1)
            p.Append(new Run());
        Run r = p.Elements<Run>().First();
        RunProperties RP = r.AppendChild(new RunProperties());
        FontSize fontSize = new FontSize();
        fontSize.Val = Fontsize.ToString();
        RP.AppendChild(fontSize);
        RightToLeftText RT = new RightToLeftText()
            {
                Val = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OnOffValue(true)
            };
        RP.Append(RT);
        if (r == null || r.Elements<Text>() == null || r.Elements<Text>().ToArray().Length < 1)
            r.Append(new Text());
        Text t = r.Elements<Text>().First();
        t.Text = New.ToString();
```

those codes sets the text to the cell as RTL text but with standard font size 
if i removed the rtl codes the font size works fine
i'v tried and searched alot with no clue
any tip would be appreciated

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I.v found the answer , i needed to add

```
FontSizeComplexScript fontSizeComplexScript = new FontSizeComplexScript() { Val = Fontsize.ToString() };
```

and it worked very well
thank you all
please mark this as answered